# How can someone hack our bank account?

Tags: bank-account, fraud, online-banking, online-payment, transaction

Can someone hack and withdraw money from my bank account if they have my full name, bank name, last four digit bank account number and my phone number. Yes or No, Please explain why?

Comment: Your bank account isn't going to be hacked with only the last 4 digits of your account.  However, if the bank's records are successfully hacked into then everyone's  accounts will be at risk.

Comment: "hack" is a rather meaningless word. There are a number of things that only you should be able to do with your bank account, such as view the balance, spend the money, and terminate the account. It should be obvious that these are not equal. Even so, no bank should allow anyone to even view your balance even if they had your **full** account number - your employer might very well have that.

Comment: Account numbers are *not* private information; they are printed on every check you write. (They may be considered personal *protected* information depending on jurisdiction, but there is no assumption that you and only you know what your account number is for authentication purposes.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My full name on bank, my last four digit account number and they also know my phone number that link to my bank account. So, Will they able to hacked my account through this information.

Maybe. It's hard to say how secure your bank is, but this is the *sort* of information that *might* be enough to take over your bank account, depending on the bank. I wouldn't risk it, personally. It's not clear to me why you want to do this, but one possible reason is that a stranger has asked you to send them money, and now they are asking to see the transaction.

If that's the case, then you may already be the victim of a scam. There are numerous scams which involve unknown people contacting victims and asking them to send money through all sorts of different channels. I'm not specifically familiar with scams involving Google Pay, but it would not surprise me if this were the case. In general, unsolicited requests for money are a red flag regardless of how the money is transmitted and regardless of who or what the scammer claims to be or represent.

On the other hand, if you initiated this transaction, in exchange for some real good or service, it may be legitimate, depending on the circumstances. You should still make sure that the agreement is in writing, that this person is an identifiable individual or works for an identifiable company, and that you have the practical ability to initiate a chargeback or pursue some other form of redress in the event that they fail to produce the good or service that you purchased. Unless, of course, you've already received the good or service and just need to pay for it.

As for your immediate problem, I would ask the recipient whether they received a receipt from Google (they should have). If they did not, then you should inform Google that you sent the money to the wrong person, and ask them to reverse the transaction. However, I would suggest telling the recipient that you are going to do this. If they suddenly change their mind and assert that they *did* receive the cash, that's another red flag.

If you believe that you have been scammed, you should cease all contact with the recipient, notify Google, and hopefully they can pull your funds back. You should do this as soon as is practical, if indeed it is a scam.

Answer (score 3):

No. If you are in the US, then that information is printed on every check you write.

Answer (score 2):

"Hacking" these days means either:

- They guessed your password or tricked you into telling them
- They tricked the bank into thinking the hacker was you (e.g. "forgot password)
- They got into the bank's database and stole a large number of account info, and yours happened to be one of them

They can do these anyway, and knowing your full name or a few digits of the account number does not make it much easier or harder. As an exercise, consider:

- Everyone knows Jeff Bezos's full name
- Everyone knows he has money
- There are only so many banks (and he probably has accounts with most of them)
- There are only 10,000 possible last four numbers so it's not that hard to guess, especially if many people are trying

So if these thing allowed you to hack someone's bank account, how come the evil hackers didn't hack Bezos?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to claim that there aren't places in the world where this information may be sufficient.

However, here in the SEPA area (≈ Euro zone), all this information including the *full* account number (which actually includes bank and branch as well) are usually handed out on pretty much every business letter.

- Full account number incl. bank and branch is required to pay money into this account. Account owner is not really checked any more since the account numbers contain check digits.
- Depending on the legal form, a business may have to state full name of owner in their official letters
- Their web page (here in Germany, this varies substantially across countries) has to state a responsible person and a fast way of reaching this person. That is often the same business owner.
- For obvious reasons, businesses want to spread their phone number.
  A small business opening a bank account may find that the bank wants to use the phone number that said business uses for official communication (as part of their IDing the account holder [which is part of anti-money-laundering requirements]).

In order to even only see the account, other authentication factors are used. Nowadays typically 2 other factors such as a password and a TAN/OTP.